# Android Room - how to get the new data only?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android, android-diffutils

What is a result of this `Dao` method after inserting some `message`s in the database:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM messages")
Flowable<List<Message>> getMessages();
```

1 - **ALL** `message`s stored in the database will be emitted after this change

or

2 - Only the **DIFFERENCE** beetwen new and old `message`s will be emitted after the change?

In which documents is it specified? If first, what should I do to get the difference - something like `DiffUtils` or there are other approaches?

P.S. What if I **DELETE** some messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **All** the messages stored in the database will be emitted.
2. To get the difference, the recommended approach is to use [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) as you mentioned. There is a lot of information about how it works and how to implement it. Just to mention a few here you have this [Mindorks' tutorial](https://medium.com/mindorks/diffutils-improving-performance-of-recyclerview-102b254a9e4a) and [@iammert tutorial](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00)
3. You can write a different query if you don't want to get all the messages every time some of them change. This depends on your use case but, for example, you can have a query that returns all the messages after a certain date if you know that older messages will not change.
4. If you the delete some messages, the result of the query will change. Therefore, you will have all the messages emitted again.
5. I would use `LiveData<List<Message>>` instead. The behavior is the same and you don't need to worry about disposing your subscriptions, nor worry about configuration changes. However, I would use `Single` or `Maybe` when you have to return a single result.

**Update:** instead of getting all the messages and seeing the difference between them using DiffUtils, you can retrieve a subset of the messages and update it on demand. The new [Paging library in Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) helps you doing this. Again, there is a lot of information around about how to do this so I am not going to put the details of the implementation here because it is out of the scope of the question, but here you have [one of the many tutorials](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-recyclerview-pagination-with-paging-library-using-mvvm-rxjava-dagger-2-and-livedata-b0489ecbbfc0) available.

Comment: It may lead in a huge useless memory consumption if all messages will be emitted and  `DiffUtils` does not change this situation...

Comment: @isabsent true, but there is no other alternative if you keep on using that query. However, you can make your application more efficient if you restrict the result of the query by using additional parameters (getting the messages after an specific date), or even better using a Pagination strategy (you can use the Paging library provided by android)

Comment: Is this still relevant? Is Livedata still the way to go